# How to replace fragment in nav_host_fragment with another fragment

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_home,R.id.nav_events, 
       R.id.nav_slideshow,
       R.id.search,R.id.profile).setDrawerLayout(drawer).build();
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);

NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

I want to add another fragment in navhost fragment say notification fragment but it is not there in navigation menu, rather it is at top of tool bar.

So I want, when I click the notification icon, notification_fragment should be inflated in nav host fragment.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the [deep linking documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#explicit)?

Answer (score 1):

```
navController.navigate(R.id.mainFragment, bundle);
```

You can use the above code to change fragment inside onclick listeners.
R.id.mainFragment will be the id of the fragment you want to show. You have to add this fragment to the navigation graph. 'bundle' is optional is you want to pass any data to the incoming fragment.